# Graphs with large automorphism groups

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

While most graphs have trivial aut group (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08006900, [https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-04.pdf](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1963-04.pdf), and also from sage simulations), I am interested in undirected graph families which have large aut groups (preferably exponential in the number of vertices). 
Circulant graphs are one example of a graph family which have a non trivial aut group. (They contain the n-cycle), but I am not sure what conditions they need to satisfy for the aut group to be larger than n. (perhaps related to the spectrum of the graph) 
I am wondering if there exist infinite families of graphs with large aut group, or methods to construct graphs of a given degree with large aut group. (rather than just isolated examples like the complete graph and the discrete graph)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph

Comment: The discrete graphs (no edges) and the complete graphs (all edges) both have the largest possible automorphism group for their size, the full symmetric group on the vertices. Do you want more conditions than what you’ve stated?

Comment: I meant apart from those two examples yes. Added that in the question

Comment: For any fixed graph $H$, the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $H$ has $S_n$ as a subgroup of its automorphism group, and thus the family of such disjoint unions has the size of the automorphism group growing exponentially in the number of vertices. I think you might need to nail down some additional conditions to avoid examples like this, which I suspect are not what you intended.

Comment: The line graphs of complete graphs on $n$ vertices have the symmetric group on $n$ points as their automorphism group, and have only $\binom{n}2$ vertices.

Comment: More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are two graphs then one can construct various product graphs $X \times Y$ (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) and these have automorphism group at least as large as the product of the automorphism groups of $X$ and of $Y$. So one can consider e.g. products of cyclic and complete graphs.

Comment: Instead of "methods to construct graphs of a given degree with large aut group" you mean methods to construct graphs of a given **order** with large aut group?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to look might be families of graphs that are created to test graph isomorphism algorithms. For example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03686.pdf) (Benchmark Graphs for Practical Graph Isomorphism) describes the Cai-Fürer Immerman gadgets and Miyazaki graphs.

If you need actual examples of such graphs, it might be convenient to download them from the Nauty/Traces website [here](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Graphs.html), although they may be in other databases of graphs elsewhere.